# Catch not found error by certain route prefix [Laravel]

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm building web api along side with website in laravel 5.2, when user visit unavailable url on my web like `http://stage.dev/unavailable/link` then it will throw on 404 page on errors view resource, then i want to catch with different way if user try to access my API with unavailable url like `http//stage.dev/api/v1/unavailable/link`, then i want to return `json/xml` response

```
{
  'status' : 'not found',
  'code' : 404,
  'data' : []
}
```

not the view, is there a way to detect it by url prefix 'api/*' or how.., maybe another approach with similar result, so the device/client which access it could proceed by standard format (i have simple format in all json response)

```
{
  'status' : 'success|failed|restrict|...',
  'api_id' : '...',
  'token' : '...',
  'data' : [
    {'...' : '...'},
    {'...' : '...'},
    ...
  ]
}
```

**SOLVED**

I figure out something after read answer from [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/614112/chris) and [Alexey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1227923/alexey-mezenin) this approach works for me i add couples of lines in `handler.php` at `render()` method,

```
    if($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException || $this->isHttpException($e)) {
        if($request->segment(1) == 'api' || $request->ajax()){
            $e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
            $result = collect([
                'request_id' => uniqid(),
                'status' => $e->getStatusCode(),
                'timestamp' => Carbon::now(),
            ]);
            return response($result, $e->getStatusCode());
        }
    }
```

my header request respond 404 error code and return json data like i want..

Comment: If it's solved, and was of your own accord, please submit an answer and mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out something after read answer from **Chris** and **Alexey** this approach works for me i add couples of lines in handler.php at render() method,,

```
    if($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException || $this->isHttpException($e)) {
        if($request->segment(1) == 'api' || $request->ajax()){
            $e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
            $result = collect([
                'request_id' => uniqid(),
                'status' => $e->getStatusCode(),
                'timestamp' => Carbon::now(),
            ]);
            return response($result, $e->getStatusCode());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's a better way to do that, but you could create custom error 404 handler. Follow [this tutorial](http://www.techigniter.in/tutorials/create-custom-error-pages-in-laravel-5/), but change `case 404` part to something like this:

```
if(str_contains(Request::url(), 'api/v1/')){
    return response()->json(your_json_data_here);
}else{
    return \Response::view('custom.404',array(),404);
}
```

Comment: i know how to create custom 404 page.. your answer is not what i mean, that just check if url contain 'api/v1/' string, when user access 'api/v1/article/vote' otherside that url doesn't exist and your condition will be true..

Comment: This check will occur only if page is not found. Please read tutorial and my answer again.

Comment: oh i'm sorry i didn't realize you type `case 404` reference your tutorial,, yes maybe it works but in laravel 5.2 $e variable is instance of `ModelNotFoundException` if you want to check isHttpException($e) you need to parse the exception

Answer (score 1):

Inside `App\Exception\Handler.php` you have a `render` method which can be handy for general purpose error catching and handling.

In this case you can also use the `request()->ajax()` method to determine if it's ajax. It does this by checking that certain headers are present, in particular:

```
'XMLHttpRequest' == $this->headers->get('X-Requested-With')
```

Anyway, back to the render method in `Handler.php`.

You can do something like:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{        

    if($e instanceof HttpException && $e->getStatusCode() == 404) {
        if (request()->ajax()) {
            return response()->json(['bla' => 'foo']);
        } else {
            return response()->view('le-404');
        }
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Comment: but api request is not transferred over ajax,, and in laravel 5.2 if you check variable $e is not instance of HttpException but ModelNotFoundException,, and still i want keep the request headers return code 404